# Java application freezing

Tags: java, eclipse, refresh

I am very new to java. Very. Like I basically started today. I have previous programming knowledge in other languages, like c, c++, PHP, javascript, etc, but I can't figure this one out. I started watching tutorials on Youtube about how to make a video game in Java(videos from theChernoProject), but about 7 episodes in, I came across a problem, where we have our window, and we paint a black rectangle across the whole thing, and the application freezes my whole computer. Here is my code:

```
package com.darksun.theonetruemike.rain;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int width = 300;
    public static int height = width / 16 * 9;
    public static int scale = 3;

    private Thread thread;
    private JFrame frame;
    private boolean running = false;

    public Game(){
        Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
        setPreferredSize(size);

        frame = new JFrame();
    }

    public synchronized void start(){
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        running = false;
        try{
            thread.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        while(running){
            update();
            render();
        }
    }

    public void update(){

    }

    public void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();

        if(bs == null){
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Game game = new Game();
        game.frame.setResizable(false);
        game.frame.setTitle("Rain");
        game.frame.add(game);
        game.frame.pack();
        game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        game.frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
    }

}
```

I'm using eclipse to make this project(highly against my will), and when I press the Debug button, the window appears, and my computer freezes, resulting in having to force quit the entire computer. Please help if you can, and thanks for help ahead of time!

Comment: How do you know it freezes, it doesn't appear to do anything. Also. You main loop is probably going to overspend, which could consume your CPU cycles...

Comment: I know it freezes because I press the close button and it takes about 5 minutes of doing nothing, then I have to force quit my computer

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the thread?

Comment: And something like Thread.sleep(16); after you call render

Comment: When I run this render is being called 7500ish times per second, that is a bit excessive.

Comment: What jdk are you using?

Comment: I just am typing what the tutorial types, so that is how I am learning

Comment: Thank you, @MadProgrammer, pausing for 16ms helped, and it no longer crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since i have low reputation, i will post my comment as answer, try not to -rep

i copied your code to netbeans, a black console like window appears, nothing happens, but it doesnt freeze, but the JVM is using about 50% of cpu

Comment: yes, i figured it out, it't because my computer couldn't handle the number of processes. Thanks though, it helped

Comment: i'm happy i could help :)